# Best Practice for Arrays you will Write to Often

Tags: contract-design, ipfs, database

I want to build an App with an array data structure that I would like to keep private. So far, I've wanted to build it between IPFS and Ethereum. But what would be best practice for an array that I want to keep private and will want to change often?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Everything on the Ethereum mainnet blockchain is public so to store private data you'll need to either

- store a reference to an IPFS hash where the data is encrypted and the client decrypts it
- store the data encrypted on Ethereum and decrypt it off-chain